# How do I find out the class of an object coming from an Object Input Stream?

Tags: java

I'm doing a java project, and I need to check if a given object from an input stream is of a type "xyzsomething."

I understand that I can use instanceof, but when I check instanceof to the class name "xyzsomething," it gives me a compile error, because it doesn't recognize the class name. What should I do?

edit: Sorry, I'm new at this. Here is the code and error:

```
 if ((input instanceof ShotCoordinatesServer))  <--- error occurs on this
                                                it won't recognize class.
 {
      checkHit((ShotCoordinatesServer)input); <--- error occurs on this too
 }

ERROR: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: ...Did you make sure you typed it right? Please [edit] your question to add the relevant snippet of code.

Comment: Just changed it to include my code. It's probably a really simple error, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: This is not the reason for your error. Where does the error occur? Post more code please.

Comment: Changed it again. Is this enough? (Sorry this is my first post, still learning how to write effective and clear questions :) )

Comment: The error means the class `ShotCoordinatesServer` is not available to the compiler.  Are you sure you have that class (or its entire package) imported?  Is it visible at that point in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
 ObjectInputStream ois = ...
 Object something = ois.readObject();
 if (something instanceof MyClass) {
    ((MyClass) something).someMethodOfMyClass();
 }
```

This should compile ... provided that the symbol `MyClass` is known at compile time.

---

In your example, it appears that `ShotCoordinatesServer` is not known at compile time.  The fix may simply be to `import` the class.  Or you may need to add it to the compile-time classpath.

If the class is simply unavailable at compile, then you cannot use `instanceof` and typecasts.  Instead you are going to need to use reflection ... or maybe test and cast to an interface type that is a supertype of `ShotCoordinatesServer`.

But if you simply want to find out the name of the class you just read ...

```
 System.out.println(something.getClass().getName());
```